# How to solve the following delayed differential equations with periodic delay effect?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to solve the following differential equations

$\partial_{t} f(t) = - a f(t)-a \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(t-n \tau) \cdot \Theta(t-n \tau)$

I learned the way for solving the equations from the following example
[System of delay differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175224/system-of-delay-differential-equations)
The following is my code

```
Module[{a = 1},
sol1 = f[t] /. NDSolve[{f'[t] == -a*f[t], f[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 3}];
sol2 =  NDSolve[{f'[t] == -a*f[t] - a*f[t - 3]*HeavisideTheta[t-3], f[t /; t <= 3] == sol1}, f, {t, 0, 6}];
Plot[Evaluate[f[t] /. sol2], {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

But errors happens. So what's the correct way for solving this kind of delayed differential equations? I think this is a very simple delayed differential equation and I hope Mathematica can do this in a simple and elegant way!

**Update:**
Thanks for user72028's answer, I know how to solve the equations for N=1, However, When I want to solve N=2,erros happens, the following is the code

```
a = 1;
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a f[t], f[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, 
   f[t], {t, 0, 3}];
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a f[t] - a f[t - 3] UnitStep[t - 3], 
    f[t /; t <= 3] == sol1}, f[t], {t, 0, 6}];
sol3 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a f[t] - a f[t - 3] UnitStep[t - 3] - 
      a f[t - 6] UnitStep[t - 6], f[t /; t <= 6] == sol2}, 
   f[t], {t, 0, 9}];
Plot[sol3, {t, 0, 9}]
```

The errors are

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
NDSolveValue::idelay: Initial history needs to be specified for all variables for delay-differential equations.
NDSolveValue::dsvar: 0.00018385714285714286` cannot be used as a variable.
NDSolveValue::dsvar: 0.18385732653061226` cannot be used as a variable.
General::stop: Further output of NDSolveValue::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {6.06141} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {6.24508} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {6.42876} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: "Solve::ratnz" is informational, not an error.

Comment: Oh, it's my fault. I have updated all of the error informations on the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for any number of steps (for instance, `5`) is

```
With[{a = 1, τ = 3, m = 4}, tm = (m + 1) τ; 
    s = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a*Sum[f[t - n τ] UnitStep[t - n τ], {n, 0, m}], 
        f[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, tm}];
    Plot[s[t], {t, 0, tm}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, f}, 
        LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]]
```

[image]

This particular problem can be solved symbolically be replacing `NDSolveValue` by `DSolveValue`, but I assume that the OP has in mind a more complicated ODE in practice.

Incidentally, `f[0] == 1` should be an adequate initial condition, because solving the ODE as written in this answer does not require knowledge of `f[t]` for `t < 0`.  However, `NDSolve` error checking does not realize this and complains before solving the ODE without difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

1. Your `sol1` is a *list* containing the desired function of `t`. Either extract the first part of that list, or use `NDSolveValue` with `f[t]` in the second argument to return said function of `t` directly.
2. The "non-numerical value for a derivative at `t == 3`" message arises from `HeavisideTheta[0]` not having a numerical value. Use `UnitStep` instead.

Altogether:

```
a = 1;
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a f[t], f[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, f[t], {t, 0, 3}];
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == -a f[t] - a f[t - 3] UnitStep[t - 3], f[t /; t <= 3] == sol1}, f[t], {t, 0, 6}];
Plot[sol2, {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Plot of sol2]

Comment: Thank you so much for answeing the question! This really helps me a lot. Your answer works for me. However, When I continue adding the delayed terms. There are erros, I have updated the errors in the questions. Do you have any idea on this error message?